# CSS How move up block?

Tags: css

Apply please the idea of how to remove the distance between the blocks? For the third block belonged to the first. Due to the properties of float 3rd after the second begins. And I can not figure out how to do to it was higher.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo. Nobody can solve your problem by image.

Comment: http://agestor.com/pharmacy/capsules.html?mode=list

Comment: Why you don't use negative margin-top?

Comment: Then the names of some places will go to another block ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the blocks are out of order. What you call #4 appears to be rendering before #3. This means that the clear: right on it forces the description downwards.

In order to fix this, change the order of your rendered HTML, as shown in the below screenshot from dev tools. Dragging the .desc.std above the .product-secondary solves your issue nicely.

[image: Changing the content order]

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `margin:0` to `.price-box` and `.desc`.

**Problem:** `.desc` pushes `.desc` to down, however, you can use the below rules.

```
.products-list .product-shop .price-box {
    margin: 0;
}

.products-list .product-shop .desc {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `float: none;` to `.desc` elements